# Concatenate two columns in where

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a variable which contains a full name and a table which has the names separated into first name and last name.

I am trying to update records where the first name joined with the last name equals the variable.

```
$row[1]="Joe Bloggs"

$sql = "UPDATE staff SET deductions='$row[15]', $phonepayment = '$row[16]' WHERE firstname.' '.lastaname= $row[1]";
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: WHERE firstname+'  '+lastaname= $row[1]"; concatenation in sql using +, not .

Comment: You trying to do it and what you achieve? Errors? Please rewrite question to be more concrete.

Comment: Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '38.86' WHERE firstname+ ' '+ lastname = Alis Rose' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) :

```
UPDATE staff
SET deductions='$row[15]', $phonepayment = '$row[16]'
WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastaname) = $row[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below query,you can combine strings using + operator.

```
   $row[1]="Joe Bloggs"

     $sql = "UPDATE staff 
                 SET deductions='$row[15]', $phonepayment = '$row[16]' 
                 WHERE firstname+' '+lastaname= $row[1]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE firstname + ' ' + lastname = $row[1]
```